# Align image to center with Tailwind and ReactJS

Tags: css, reactjs, tailwind-css

Using Tailwind With ReactJS I'm trying to align an image to the center but I can't, this is my code:

```
    <div class="grid md:grid-cols-2 gap-1 place-content-center">
      <div className="hidden md:block my-10 md:ml-10 shadow rounded-sm">
        <img 
            src={ Logo }
            alt= "Logo"
            className="object-none object-center"
        />
      </div>
      <form className="my-10 md:mr-10 bg-white shadow rounded-sm px-10 py-5">
...

      </form>
    </div>
```

Here is a screenshot of the result:

[image]

Comment: Can you post a picture of the result you are trying to achieve?

Answer (score 2):

Make the `div` parent `flex` instead of `block`, add `justify-center`

like this :

```
<div class="grid place-content-center gap-1 md:grid-cols-2">
  <div class="hidden md:inline-flex my-10 md:ml-10 shadow rounded-sm w-full  justify-center">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/200" alt="Logo" class="object-none object-center" />
  </div>
  <form class="my-10 md:mr-10 bg-white shadow rounded-sm px-10 py-5">...</form>
</div>
```

have a look https://play.tailwindcss.com/lQAKX22Qf7

Or you could just add `mx-auto` to `img`

Answer (score 0):

Okay so I suppose you just want to align the image to the center of that grid item, in that case you can just simply add `justify-self-center` class into the `div` that contain the image, something like this:

```
 <div className="grid md:grid-cols-2 gap-1 place-content-center">
      <div className="hidden md:block my-10 md:ml-10 shadow rounded-sm justify-self-center">
        <img 
            src={ Logo }
            alt= "Logo"
            className="object-none object-center"
        />
      </div>
      <form className="my-10 md:mr-10 bg-white shadow rounded-sm px-10 py-5">
...

      </form>
    </div>
```

Also I noticed there's a typo problem at the outer `div`, it should be `className` instead of `class`.
Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

you need to add `m-auto` to image. you can [see here](https://play.tailwindcss.com/XoHd1zowU2)

```
<div class="grid place-content-center gap-1 grid-cols-2">
  <div class="my-10 shadow rounded-sm w-full justify-center">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/200" alt="Logo" class="object-none object-center m-auto" />
  </div>
  <form class="my-10 bg-white shadow rounded-sm px-10 py-5">...</form>
</div>
```